# How to find the current max_parallel_workers value in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

To enable parallel query planning Postgresql has many settings like `max_parallel_workers` and many more. In Postgresql docs how these values must be tweaked is mentioned, however how can we see the current value of such configurations?

Comment: Maybe using `SHOW`? e.g. `SHOW max_worker_processes;`

Comment: Thanks :)
I tried SELECT, didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`SHOW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-show.html) you can get the current values of many system variables and paths.

```
SHOW max_parallel_workers;

 max_parallel_workers 
----------------------
 8
(1 Zeile)
```

maybe also interesting ..

```
SHOW max_worker_processes;

 max_worker_processes 
----------------------
 8
(1 Zeile)
```

Curious about other variables? Try `SHOW all`.